# How to create user/roles relation in UML class diagram?

Tags: java, c++, c, uml

I have few weeks searching how to create a UML class diagram for a project.

The system will manage users and roles of users  for access and maintain active session after login.

- What type of relation can I implementate between the classes?
- Are this class correct?
- Will I need other classes?

Thanks in Advance!

[image: user/roles uml class diagram]

Comment: It would help if you gave a hint about what the user was doing.  What is the application that the user is logging on to?  What scenario do you want to handle?

Comment: It is a billing system. The employees have different roles according with your job (cashier, human resources, admin, others)... Only employees and maybe the suppliers  going to have access to system.... Scenario: When user login the system need know which is your role for give access level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot at this.  Session object has a composition association with User.  (Can't have a user without a session, can't have a session without a user.)  User has a composition association with Roles.  (Can't have a user without roles, etc.)  Session constructor creates user object, user constructor creates one role object for each valid role and puts them in a collection/dictionary/array/whatever.

You don't associate role directly with the subclasses, because every type of user has roles.  User exposes valid roles through methods.  Session accesses valid roles when deciding whether or not to allow a given activity.

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe that Session and User not have direct relation, Session only exists after login is successful. I agree with the relation of User and Roles.

Comment: Although Session only exists after login is successful, the point is that Session CAN'T exist without User and a User has to have one.  This means that Session's life is tied to User's life.  While there may be another way of modeling it (Associating User with a SessionManager object, for example), a Session's lifetime is tied to a User's lifetime.  The Session has to be created within the context of a valid (i. e. successfully logged in) User, and can't be transferred to another User.  So, composition.

Comment: Lot of thanks! After fews days analysing your answer now I undertand it. Here let an IBM example of composition association... http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5JSH_9.0.0/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/ccompasn.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the Session class to be an association class between User and Roles.  Logging in to the system creates the Session which assigns capabilities depending on the type of user.

Comment: Session class only acts after login is successful for maintain active the user token... When user logout the session is deleted

Comment: OK, but you need a way to relate users to their roles.  It may be sufficient to use attributes within the user subclasses. Otherwise, create an associative class which gets the type from the user and enables access to system functions.

Comment: I agree with create an associative class... But the question is still What type of  relation? Any example? I suppose user not need roles to login... After login user needs roles for know to what part of the system has access..

Comment: The associative class manages the 1 to 1 relationship between  between user and session.  Try: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsarthlp/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcassnclss.html